# CSS/HTML - Cursor changes from pointer to I when hovering over the text inside a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an HTML link with some text inside it, that triggers a JS event. Looks something like:

[image]

The cursor changes to pointer (hand) when I hover over the link. But when I hover specifically over the part that says "Hello", it changes back to I (beam). I want it to remain a hand over the entire button.

Also, `cursor: pointer` is already in the style of the link. Without it, the link is entirely not-clickable for some reason. I can't figure out why. Aren't `a` tags supposed to be clickable without `cursor: pointer`?

Any solutions?

Comment: please add code to the question to be sure what is the problem

Comment: Is there an element inside your `<a>` that has its `cursor` property set on it already? `cursor: pointer` should not affect the clickability of the link, do you have another element on top of it?

Comment: You should try to put it in a snippet for us so we can see your intent.

Comment: Hi @lebowski like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/chwhxutd/

Comment: Hi guys, the issue was something known as z-index. I don't know what that is, but adding z-index: 9999 in the link's CSS style made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: z-index. I'm not sure what it is but I saw it in another SO post and it worked. The simple answer is to add `z-index:9999` to the CSS style of the link. I'm also not sure why the specific value 9999 works (apparently, in situations like this, a different value of z-index should also work), but it's working in my case.

I'll obviously look up z-index later. But if someone feels like shedding some light on it, please do.

Comment: It sounds like you had an element on top of your button in z-space. If you were to think of your elements like layers, increasing the `z-index` moves your button layer above the others. Using `9999` as the value is likely overkill. Depending on the `z-index` of the other elements around, you may only need it to be `1`.